# How should I terminate a func in F#

Tags: f#

```
let Trans(DirPath:string) =
    if ( numOfVmFiles(DirPath) > 1) then //if there are more than 1 vm files in the directory
            Init("")
    let VmFiles = ListOfVmFiles(DirPath)
    for VmFile in VmFiles do // for each vm file
            ReadFile(VmFile)
```

I got this error:
Error       Block following this 'let' is unfinished. Expect an expression. 
what should I write?thznk u

Comment: function should return something

Comment: The error must be somewhere else.  This code compiles for me as long as I define the referenced functions (numOfVmFiles, Init, etc).

Comment: how can I write what the func return? I dont know the syntax...

Comment: Just write the value on a separate line at the right indentation level, there is no keyword needed.

Answer (score 3):

The existing answers give you good hints on how to write your code better. You said you are getting an error:

> Block following this 'let' is unfinished. Expect an expression.

This typically indicates missing `=` or wrong indentation after the end of your function (or some easy to miss syntax error like that). In the snippet you posted, all syntax looks good to me, so I suspect there is something wrong elsewhere too. The following gives no errors:

```
let numOfVmFiles a = 0
let Init a = ()
let ListOfVmFiles a = []
let ReadFile a = ()

let Trans(DirPath:string) =
    if ( numOfVmFiles(DirPath) > 1) then 
            Init("")
    let VmFiles = ListOfVmFiles(DirPath)
    for VmFile in VmFiles do // for each vm file
            ReadFile(VmFile)
```

You get two warnings - because variable names should be `camelCase` rather than `PascalCase`, but no error. As others said, you should probably make `Init` and `ReadFile` return something and then you need to collect the results (to make your code more functional), but that's a separate problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the function does not return a value. Functions must always return a value. If there is nothing to return, return `unit`. You can return unit as `()`.

I made some possibly incorrect assumptions here but I tried to make clear what they were. On the `trans` function I also show how you can specify the return type. It is usually best to let the compiler infer the type until it cannot. Hover over the functions and see what the compiler is telling you about the types. `string -> int -> string list` means a function takes a string and an int and returns a list of strings.

```
let init dirName = () //unit is returned... kind of like void but is actually a return value
let listOfVmFiles dirName = ["some";"files"] // list of string
let readFile path = "content of file" //string

let trans(dirPath:string) : string list = // takes a string and returns a list of string represented as string-> string list
    let vmFiles = listOfVmFiles(dirPath) // get files from path
    if(vmFiles.Length > 1) then init("") // init if more than 1 file
    List.map readFile vmFiles // return a list of the content of the files
```

If a function is performing a side-effect and does not return something then it can be done like so:

```
let trans(dirPath:string) : unit =
    let vmFiles = listOfVmFiles(dirPath)
    if(vmFiles.Length > 1) then init("")
    List.map readFile vmFiles |> ignore //ignore the result
    ()
```

This ignores the result of mapping the `readFile` function over the list and then returns `unit` using `()`.

I recommend [fsharp for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/) for learning fsharp.
Hope this helps and good luck. Although the syntax seems weird initially stick with it. It's great!

Comment: `List.map readFile` will do nothing because it uses delayed evaluation.  Change it to `List.iter`.

Comment: @RobertSim it's definitely [eagerly evaluated](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4O1TEu) and would therefore work. I'd agree that `List.iter` would be clearer, though.

Comment: I tested this and you are right- I need to understand better cases where map is lazy.

Comment: @RobertSim - `Seq.map` is lazy, but other `map` functions (`List.map`, `Array.map`, and so on) are eagerly evaluated. As a general rule, anything you do with `seq`s is lazy, and anything with lists or arrays is eager.

Comment: But it still gives me the same error:( I tried the two funcs yo wrote me...I dont need the return value only that the func "init" to run on the vmFiles.

Answer (score 1):

In F# a function returns the value of the last expression it evaluated.
In your particular case it returns unit `()`, because a `for` loop returns unit unless its body `yield`s values (in which case you would need to wrap it in a `seq`). 
As mentioned in the comments, this code parses ok- your issue is with an unfinished expression elsewhere in your code.

The rewrite by Devon Buriss is a good example of best practices:

- Explicitly declare your function return value in the signature.
- `ignore` function return values if the function is only called for side effects (eg `readFile` and `init("")`).
- Prefer functional behaviors such as `map` over imperatives such as for .. do.

As an aside, relying so heavily on side effects is likely to cause you difficulties elsewhere. A more common practice with data crunching is do have a function like readFile return file contents as a seq, and pipe the result to downstream processing:

```
List.map readFile vmFiles
|> seq.Concat // concatenate the file outputs
|> processContents
```

Whether or not this is the right thing for you depends on what exactly you intend to do with the contents of each file.